# Django Template Inheritance not fully working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, jinja2, web-development-server

base.html

[image: Base .html]

Blogpage.html

[image: Blogpage.html]

Results:

[image: Results]

[image: Views inside my app]

[image: Views inside my main app]

The base template is added but i can't insert contents between {% block content%} {% endblock %}. Please help.  Thanks in advance . :)

Comment: add your views code. which template you are rendering from your views?

Comment: views.py inside my app

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BlogPost

# Create your views here.

def show_blog(request):
    article = BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'article/blogPage.html', {'article': article})


views.py inside my main app

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

Comment: Both the views.py are added

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use {% endblock content %} as there are two blocks of code.

Just let the template engine know which block is ending where. Like {% endblock content %} and {% endblock foot %}